# getting controls inside a repeater in javascript function for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I put several controls inside a repeater control with id = "rpContacts". The repeater is placed inside a table with id = "ParentTable". 
I need  to validate the control inside the repeater(say a text box- txtLastName) for duplicate value with value inside another text box outside the repeater.
The validation function is called by a custom Validator which is outside the repeater.

The problem is I could not get the client id of neither the repeater nor the controls inside it in my javascript function.

I could get the values of controls inside the repeater if I give their rendered ClientId like

```
$find('ctl00_body_content_rpContacts_ctl00_txtLastName').Value;
```

But this client id of control wil change for each row of the repeater.

ie. for the txtZip in 2nd repeater row its id will be `'ctl00_body_content_rpContacts_ctl01_txtLastName'.`

Any suggestions how I can do this validation.

--

Repeater code:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="AjaxPanel1" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="conditionalPostback">
    <table class="ParentTable">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpContacts" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr> <td> 
                    <table class="ParentTable" runat="server" id="tblEC"> 
                        <tr> <td> <div> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Width="180"/> 
                        </div> </td> </tr> 
                    </table> 
                </td> </tr> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:Repeater> 
    </table> 
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Comment: give a class name to repeater . then it render your repeater . it will generate same class for all the controls.

Comment: I have added the class as <asp:Repeater  ID="rpContacts" runat="server" class="rpEC">. But it gives error ,'Repeater' does not have a public property named 'class'.

Comment: can you show your repeater code ?

Comment: <code><telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="AjaxPanel1" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="conditionalPostback">
<table class="ParentTable"> 
<asp:Repeater  ID="rpContacts" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="ParentTable" runat="server" id="tblEC"> 
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Width="180"/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel><code>

Comment: see the below answer. hope that will help you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate your controls this way:

<strike>$find('.rpContacts').Value;</strike>

```
//your javascript code
var elemArray = document.getElementsByClassName('rpContacts');
for(var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++){
    var elem = elemArray[i].value;
}

//your aspx code
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="rpContacts"></asp:TextBox>
....
```

Comment: I have tried this. When I tried $find('.rpContacts').Value; it gives error "Cannot read property 'Value' of null". $find('.rpContacts') is rendered as Null here

Comment: this is your javascript error it doesn't related to the class property, I'll update the answer for you.

Comment: When I tried  var elemArray = document.getElementsByClassName('rpContacts'); it gives elemArray with NodeList[0] and length:0 . is there any way to get the value in controls specific to each row in that repeater?

Answer (score 1):

here is simple demo through which you can get the id and value of controls inside repeater

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate >              
                <asp:TextBox ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' Font-Bold="true"/><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and jquery would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {             
            $('[id*=Repeater1_lblSubject]').on('change', function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var value = $('#' + id).val();                  
                alert(id+'_'+value);
            });
        });
    </script>
```